# Call .reg File from Excel-VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I want to call a .reg File out of my VBA script. I'm using Office/Excel 2013. 
I know Excel can't run these files by itself, so i need to call the file via shell. The code i wrote doesn't work:

```
Sub deactivateHyperlinkWarnings()
    Dim x
    x = Shell("cmd /C C:\TEMP\DisableHyperlinkWarnings.reg")
End Sub
```

I found this piece of code somewhere on the web, but its not working. I don't even get an error message. The .reg File is located in C:\TEMP

What do i need to write to make it work?

**Plus:** Is it possible to suppress the MessageBoxes that are displayed when i run the .reg-File? When i start the file manually, i need to Hit "OK" like 3 Times. The people who are working with the Excelsheet later on shouldn't be seeing these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running `cmd` try to run `reg`. So in your case it should be `x = Shell("reg import C:\TEMP\DisableHyperlinkWarnings.reg")`

More info [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true)